# git hook not working when pushing via http to windows

Tags: git, push, hook, githooks

I am trying to set up a central bare git-repo with a post-receive-hook. When I push changes to this repo the post-receive-hook starts as expected. 
Now, I want to access this repo via http. When I push changes to this repo now, the post-receive-hook does not start as not git, but the web-server is making the changes. 
To resolve this issue I found the solution to use Smart http. But somehow it is not working. I can push changes, but the hook doesn't start either.

Maybe you have an idea about where to look for the misconfiguration or whatelse is going wrong.

Thanks for your help.

My Apache 2.4 configuration on a windows machine looks like this:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT "e:/gitBare"
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAliasMatch    "(?x)^/git/(.*/(HEAD | \
              info/refs | \
              objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
              [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
              pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
              git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
              "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"
###################
##    GIT        ##
###################
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   gitShareBare
    DocumentRoot "e:/gitBare/repo2.git"
    <Location /> 
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 192
            Require ip ::1
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Directory "e:/gitBare/repo2.git">
        DAV On
        Options +ExecCGI +Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from all
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The push is done like this:

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

Fetching remote heads...
refs/
refs/heads/
refs/tags/
updating 'refs/heads/master'
from ca186a2cc78a58969790d4a94a0c431604673a7d
to   51397c4a757a0ec9751fd2e7b9e8ab2ff7752409
sending 2 objects
done
Updating remote server info
To http://gitShareBare
ca186a2..51397c4  master -> master
```

The Logfile contains the following entries:

```
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "GET /info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 59
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "GET /HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 207 514
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "HEAD /info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "HEAD /objects/info/packs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "MKCOL /info/ HTTP/1.1" 405 228
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "LOCK /info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 476
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "GET /objects/info/packs HTTP/1.1" 200 1
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "PROPFIND /refs/ HTTP/1.1" 207 2353
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "PROPFIND /refs/heads/ HTTP/1.1" 207 1572
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "GET /refs/heads/master HTTP/1.1" 200 41
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "PROPFIND /refs/tags/ HTTP/1.1" 207 855
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "MKCOL /refs/ HTTP/1.1" 405 228
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "MKCOL /refs/heads/ HTTP/1.1" 405 234
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:33 +0100] "LOCK /refs/heads/master HTTP/1.1" 200 476
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:34 +0100] "PROPFIND /objects/51/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:34 +0100] "PROPFIND /objects/b6/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:34 +0100] "MKCOL /objects/51/ HTTP/1.1" 201 186
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:34 +0100] "MKCOL /objects/b6/ HTTP/1.1" 201 186
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:34 +0100] "PUT /objects/51/397c4a757a0ec9751fd2e7b9e8ab2ff7752409_e1596c160891cc916e8de64aad9a1ce9d73f7191 HTTP/1.1" 201 263
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:34 +0100] "PUT /objects/b6/46f3ce303ece06a3ce4d1ec5cc1969c6cda6da_e1596c160891cc916e8de64aad9a1ce9d73f7191 HTTP/1.1" 201 263
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:35 +0100] "MOVE /objects/51/397c4a757a0ec9751fd2e7b9e8ab2ff7752409_e1596c160891cc916e8de64aad9a1ce9d73f7191 HTTP/1.1" 201 225
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:35 +0100] "MOVE /objects/b6/46f3ce303ece06a3ce4d1ec5cc1969c6cda6da_e1596c160891cc916e8de64aad9a1ce9d73f7191 HTTP/1.1" 201 225
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:36 +0100] "PUT /refs/heads/master HTTP/1.1" 204 -
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:36 +0100] "UNLOCK /refs/heads/master HTTP/1.1" 204 -
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:36 +0100] "PROPFIND /refs/ HTTP/1.1" 207 2353
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:36 +0100] "PROPFIND /refs/heads/ HTTP/1.1" 207 1572
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:36 +0100] "GET /refs/heads/master HTTP/1.1" 200 41
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:36 +0100] "PROPFIND /refs/tags/ HTTP/1.1" 207 855
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:36 +0100] "PUT /info/refs HTTP/1.1" 204 -
192.111.222.111 - - [27/Feb/2018:10:33:36 +0100] "UNLOCK /info/refs HTTP/1.1" 204 -
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the relevant error log file contents

Comment: error log was added to the question